# What happens when trying to update a file on Google Drive with no connection available?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

In my Android app I have some data that the user can store and I want it to be sync across all his devices.

For that I'm thinking about using the Google Drive API to save the data in user's Drive.

But what if I update a file and there's no connection at the moment? Does his device manages to sync it when a connection is available even if my App is closed? Or do I have to manage it within my own app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe I've tried everything and the answer is:

-We have to manage it within the App. Google Drive will throw an exception if not connected when you try to save a file.

But there may be a way to schedule this task to when a connection is available.